# Extension with a generic where clause is not beeing called

Tags: swift, generics, wrapper, associated-types

The following code works just as expected:

```
protocol Storeable {
    associatedtype Value
    func create(value: Value)
}

struct DefaultStore<V>: Storeable {
    typealias Value = V
    func create(value: V) {
        print("base impl. is called with value type: \(String(describing: V.self))")
    }
}

class Event {
    var title: String = ""
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

extension DefaultStore where Value: Event {
    func create(value: V) {
        print("event impl. is called with event: \(value.title)")
    }
}

DefaultStore().create(value: Event(title: "Dance Party")) 
// prints "event impl. is called with event: Dance Party"
DefaultStore().create(value: "a string object") 
// prints "base impl. is called with value of type: String"
```

Basically I call a function on the generic class `DefaultStore` and the compiler calls the correct implementation depending on the underlying type.

Now I have a scenario where I want the exact same thing except, that it is wrapped in another object called `Wrapper`:

```
struct Wrapper<StoreType: Storeable,ValueType> where StoreType.Value == ValueType { 
    let store: StoreType
    func create(value: ValueType) { 
        store.create(value: value)
    }
}

let defaultStore = DefaultStore<Event>()
let wrapper = Wrapper(store: defaultStore)
wrapper.create(value: Event(title: "Düsseldorfer Symphoniker"))
// prints: "base impl. is called with value of type: Event"
```

Here I expect that the extension for `Event` is called but instead the base implementation is called. Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong?

--

Update:

@matt was guessing that there might be a compile time issue: *"without the wrapper when you say `DefaultStore().create...` the Event info can be read all the way back to the DefaultStore generic parameterized type. But in your wrapper the DefaultStore is created first so it is the general type and that's all it is."*

I believe that is not the case because you can also create the `DefaultsStore` first and it's still working without the Wrapper. Also the compiler warns me if the types don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with "wrappers".

You seem to think that a `where` extension on a generic struct is a kind of substitute for some sort of dynamic dispatch, i.e. we're going to wait until *runtime*, look to see what kind of object the parameter to `create` *really* is, and dispatch accordingly. That's not how it works. Everything has to be resolved *at compile time*. At compile time, what we know is that you are not calling `create` with an Event — you are calling it with a ValueType. So it passes into the `create` with generic V.

So, for example:

```
struct Wrapper {
    let store: DefaultStore<Event>
    func create(value: Event) {
        store.create(value: value)
    }
}
```

That works the way you have in mind because we are exposing the fact that this is an Event *as far as the DefaultStore is concerned* at the point of calling `create`.

---

That's just a guess at what your confusion is.

Another possibility is you might imagine that the generic resolution of ValueType somehow "leaks" up to the resolution of V, but that's not true either.

Yet another possibility is you might suppose that a `DefaultStore<Event>` is a subtype of `DefaultStore<Storable>` or similar, as if there were dynamic dispatch for parameterized types, but that is exactly what is not the case. Everything has to be known completely *at compile time* at the call site.

Comment: But how is it possible that it's working without the `Wrapper`? If I explicitly define `Wrapper` like `let wrapper = Wrapper(store: DefaultStore<Event>())` the `StoreType.Value` is substituted with `Event`. Than calling 
`wrapper.create(value: Event(title: "Thanks answering"))` should have the same type due to  `StoreType.Value == ValueType`

Comment: It has to be a feature of Wrapper _itself_, i.e. you define Wrapper's instance property as `let store: DefaultStore<Event>`, _now_ it calls the one you expect. Otherwise you are still hiding the nature of `store` inside the protocol, and as I say, it isn't going to be magically resolved.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Unfortunately your example stops working for other types of `DefaultStore`. The idea is to be flexible with the store. I don't get how `StoreType.Value == ValueType` is not enough information for the compiler to do the right thing. If your theory is correct I can not see how it's working without Wrapper, because there the type is also unknown at compile time.

Comment: I believe it is because without the wrapper when you say `DefaultStore().create...` the Event info can be read all the way back to the DefaultStore generic parameterized type. But in your wrapper the DefaultStore is created _first_ so it is the general type and that's all it is.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion is that you think `DefaultStore<Event>` is some kind of subtype of `DefaultStore<Storable>` but it isn't. I'll add that to the list of confusions in my answer.

Comment: No this is not my confusion. When I try calling `wrapper.create(value: "a string type")` the compiler will complain at compile time with "Generic struct 'Wrapper' requires the types 'String' and DefaultStore<Event>.Value' (aka 'Event') be equivalent". Doesn't that show that the compiler has the right types already?

Comment: Well it _could_ be a bug and I could be completely wrong. There are certainly bugs. You could try reporting it at bugs.swift.org, they respond _very_ quickly.